# Does there exist a homotopy between identity function and any continuous function?

Tags: continuity, homotopy-theory, fixed-point-theorems

(My question is related to the Brouwer fixed-point theorem.)

Let $B$ be a closed ball of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Q 1. If $f : B \rightarrow B$ is a continuous function, then is there a homotopy between $id_B$ and $f$?

Assume the answer of the above question is yes. Then we can denote $\{f_r\}$ be a family of continuous functions where $0 \leq r \leq 1$ such that $\{f_r\}$ makes the homotopy between $id_B$ and $f$. By the Brouwer fixed-point theorem, the set $F_r := \{x ~|~ f_r(x) = x \}$ is nonempty for every $0 \leq r \leq 1$.

Q 2. Is there a continuous function $g: [0,1] \rightarrow B$ satisfying $g(r) \in F_r$ for every $0 \leq r \leq 1$? In other words, is there a path $g$ which passes through fixed points in the homotopy?

Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) is obviously true: the straight line homotopy $f_t=tf+(1-f)\operatorname{id}$.

(2) doesn't work.  Here is a sketch: Let $x_0,x_1$ be distinct points, $f_0=f_{1/2}=f_1=\operatorname{id}$, $f_{1/4}=x_0$, $f_{3/4}=x_1$ and fit in the homotopies in (1).  All nonidentity $f_r$ here only have $x_0$ or $x_1$ as the fixed point.  So your $g$ must jump at $r=1/2$.

Comment: If we add a condition $f_r(x) = f(r, x)$ of $B \times [0, 1]$ into  $B$ is smooth, then is the answer of (2) also negative?

Comment: Still negative, because there is a smooth function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ which is $0$ on $(-\infty,0]$, $1$ on $[1,\infty)$ and is a homeomorphism $[0,1]\to[0,1]$.